# Trigger before insert to create a primary key from name and surname

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

I need to generate a primary key char(3) for my database table "People"  from name and surname, i had old database inherited and i have to replicate this id. Example from 'John' 'Smith' i would like to generate the id 'JOS' then if there are two 'John Smith' it should go like this 'JSM' etc etc. 
So I tought I probably could do this as trigger before insert, is that really possible? if yes is it the best way to do it ? How to setup the trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cacciatore_bef_ins
BEFORE INSERT ON eddo.CACCIATORI
referencing old as "old" new as "new"
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
temp char(3);
pos number :=1;
BEGIN
temp:=genera_cod(new.nome,new.cognome,pos);
while esiste(temp)= true 
LOOP
    temp:=genera_cod(new.nome,new.cognome,pos+1)
END LOOP;
new.codcacciatore:=temp;
END
end cacciatore_bef_ins
/
```

Comment: I added the code that i'm trying to write, could you help to get this work and giving me advice if it s a really bad code

Answer (score 0):

> i had old database inherited and i **have to** replicate this id.

Says who? The fact that you inherited something *bad* doesn't mean that you have to make it *worse*. Just being curious: what would be the 3rd John Smith's primary key value? What about Joan Smadden? Yet another JOS as well as JSM.

I'd suggest you to

- keep "old" values
- keep column datatype

  - it is difficult to change primary key datatype and values because of foreign key constraints. If there are none, consider switching to something easier to maintain
- `CHAR(3)` suggests that you don't expect many rows in this table. There are (in English alphabet) 26^3 = 17.576 possible combinations. That's probably enough for what you store, but you might exceed combinations for those "John Smith" variations. How to find an available primary key? That depends on algorithm you use (I'm not sure which one  is it, based on what you described and my first question)
- finally, see whether you can use something "simpler", e.g.

  - all digits (from `000` to `999`), then
  - letter + 2 digits (e.g. `A00`, `A01`, ..., `A99`, `B00`, `B01`, ...)
  - and so on

Comment: The  table won't have too much rows, it is for a small work enviroment, to be more specific the table "People" will contain a maximum of 200 rows, no more for sure. The idea is to create something recursive that is the value does already exist, so it is not unique, it call the second letter of the name then  if it does exist also this other value it call giving the second of the surname (third of the name, third of surname etc etc..) I won't have duplicate because i have already this data but i need to program it as a trigger or something automatic. (Before they did this operation manually).

Answer (score 0):

A bad idea is still a bad idea even if data volume is small. The fact being it is a conversion from a manual system is all the more reason to change, everything else will be different anyway.  Processes which work reasonable well manually fail miserably when automated. This is a case in point.  
With a manual system reducing to 3 letters is a good, effective, efficient process. It gets me to the correct section of the file cabinet very quickly. From there I have only a few files to scan in order to locate the exact one needed. 
That is manually.  
  
In an automated system that is the exact opposite - it is ineffective, inefficient, and limited. I can guess with a high level of confidence your 3letter code derives from the first letter of first,middle,last name of the individual. (It could of course be derived from something else, but let go with it anyway.)  This is both natural and intuitive to a person and if there is more than one John O. Smith (JOS) or Joan Ophelia Saunders (JOS) - then so what there are other means(data points) to identify the exact file. Not so on an automated system. I have a hard time imagining that anyone would think of OOS as indication for Joan Ophelia Saunders. But as automated it is a very simple algorithmic change.  
 
  
If you think the 3char code lookup really needs to be maintained, and that is not a bad assumption, then add that as a column and create a non-unique index. When the user enters 'JOS', provide a list of qualifying namesand maybe another data point (like address) to choose from -just like a manual file cabinet. Then you do not need to try making then unique - indeed you do not want unique.  
  
For you Primacy key however just use an generated integer (sequence).  BTW Hint of the day. Make the 3letter code column varchar2(3) not char(3).

Comment: I understand your point of view and how inefficient could be this but i need to create a trigger like that also if it is not the best solution. In future maybe i could change this in a better and efficient way but by now for the purpose of the entire database i need a code like this that will be used in other procedure of the db will be concatted to something else